# pass a parameter which the function will ignore

Tags: python, dictionary, default-value

Say we have a simple python function with the signature:

```
def foo(first, second, third=50)
```

When I call it from my `main`, I will always have the first and second parameters, but I don't always have the third.

When I try to get the third from a dictionary I used: `third = dict['value'] if 'value' in dict.keys() else None`

The problem is that when I pass this `None` I want the function to use its default third parameter and be 50, but it just uses `None`. I also tried it with `[]`.

Is there a more elegant way to do this, except for calling the function twice, depends if `third` exists, one time with it and one time without it, as follows?

```
third = dict['value'] if 'value' in dict.keys() else None
if third:
    foo(first, second, third)
else:
    foo(first, second)
```

Comment: Are first and second arguments also elements of this `dict`? And please don't shadow built-in names - `dict` in this case. Use a descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
kwargs = {'third': dict['value']} if 'value' in dict else {}
foo(first, second, **kwargs)
```

The first line creates a `kwargs` dictionary which only contain a key `third` if there's `value` in `dict`, otherwise it's empty. And while calling the function, you can just spread that `kwargs` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Function objects in Python have a special property `__defaults__`. It's a tuple with default argument values. So you can easily get default value for `third` from there:

```
def foo(first, second, third=50):
    return third

dict = {}
print(foo(10, 20, dict.get('value', foo.__defaults__[0])))  # prints 50

dict = {"value": 100}
print(foo(10, 20, dict.get('value', foo.__defaults__[0])))  # prints 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if dict.get('value'):
    def foo(first, second, third)
else:
    def foo(first, second)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about redefining your function like this:

```
def foo(first, second, third):
    if third == None:
        third = 50
    """ Your code here """
```

or 
`third = dict['value'] if 'value' in dict.keys() else 50`

Comment: I almost upvoted before you added second option which takes default argument value out of function's definition. This ruined your otherwise good answer. Good luck refactoring your code if the function is called from 100 different places and you need to change the default from 50 to 40...

Answer (score 0):

You can group the args with list comprehension:

```
def foo(first,second,third=50): 
    print(first,second,third) 

args=[ a for a in [10,20,d.get("third",None)] if a!=None ]

foo(*args)                                                                                                           
10 20 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. When calling your function do this:

```
foo(first, second, third=50)
```

third should take the value when passed like this.

You can check what's passed as third

```
if None in third:
    # do this
else:
    # do something else
```